Failed to load info.plist from Bundle at path error on Xcode 16 while using XCFramework
When I try to build the app on the simulator or device on Xcode 16, the build gets succeed but I get following error when it is about to launch on device or Simulator:

I tried with different build setting, "Do not embed" and "Embed and sign" setting as well, but still it gives error.
NOTE: It works on Xcode 15 versions but issue occurs only on Xcode 16
